# find command not found for function method

Tags: bash

I'm trying to output the total word count in all files in directory a, but when I run my .sh script, I get an error "find: command not found" at the `find "$1"...` line. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

```
function count_files () {
    find "$1" -type f -exec cat {} \+ | wc -w #outputs error here
}

density_a="$(count_files "a")"
```

Comment: Typically this happens after your script has overwritten the variable `PATH` (which is why folks are supposed to use lowercase characters for their own variable names -- variables meaning to the shell or OS are all-uppercase, so avoiding that namespace prevents conflicts). Anyhow -- test that the code in your question reproduces the problem when it's the only thing in a script; as it is, this doesn't have that effect, so the question is out of compliance with http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: re: the aforementioned naming convention, see relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, paragraph 4.

Comment: As an aside, the `function` keyword has no benefit -- it just makes your code less portable; consider leaving it out, ie. `count_files() {`, with no `function` before. And as another aside, there's no need to use a backslash to escape `+` -- that character isn't a regex or syntax when used unquoted, unlike the `;` used for some other types of `find -exec` invocation.

Comment: ...but, reiterating the big picture: Right now, the code in the question doesn't reproduce the problem stated; be sure to test *in isolation* when pulling something out of a larger program to make sure it still reproduces the problem on its own.

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that whichever user is running that script does not have the find binary in its path.

Try replacing find with a full path to the find binary. (if neither of these work use the output of "which find").

```
/sbin/find "$1" -type f -exec cat {} \+ | wc -w #outputs error here
```

or

```
/bin/find "$1" -type f -exec cat {} \+ | wc -w #outputs error here
```

Comment: hmm, neither works. I am the user running the script and in another script, I ran `find . -type f | wc -l` (not inside a function) perfectly fine. The shbang at the top of the script is `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: If you run a find command locally that works and then copy/paste the exact command into the script does it still fail?

Comment: Entirely likely that it does work on the command line and fail in a script. I'll bet dollars to doughnuts the script the OP is running is doing something like `for PATH in ...` before it reaches the point where they're failing (so trying to fully-qualify the path, as you're advising them to do, is applying a bandaid rather than finding and solving the real source of the problem).

Comment: ...the right thing to do, in this kind of case, is to insist that the OP actually provide a real and *complete* reproducer, such that we can get to the root cause of their problem, rather than bumbling around with guesses that are liable to paper over the immediate problem but leave the underlying issue intact.